# Submitting HTML form multiple times with different values

Tags: javascript

Reading a list box(dpAddress) where I have listed multiple IP addresses. I select few of them, and want to send a request to each of selected IP using username-password-domain provided in another form (loginForm). I have verified that the loop works 2 times if I have selected 2 IP address in list. but it's opening only one new tab.

I want to open multiple tabs in same window of a browser with result after form submission. How can I do that?

```
function formSubmit1()
    {
     len = document.dpForm.dpAddress.length
     i = 0

     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (document.dpForm.dpAddress[i].selected) {
            alert(document.dpForm.dpAddress[i].selected)
            var f = document.createElement("form");
            f.setAttribute('method',"post");


            var user = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
            user.setAttribute('type',"text");
            user.setAttribute('name',"user");
            user.setAttribute('value',document.loginForm.user.value);

            var pass = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
            pass.setAttribute('type',"text");
            pass.setAttribute('name',"pass");
            pass.setAttribute('value',document.loginForm.pass.value);

            var domain = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
            domain.setAttribute('type',"text");
            domain.setAttribute('name',"domain");
            domain.setAttribute('value',document.loginForm.domain.value);

            f.appendChild(user);
            f.appendChild(pass);
            f.appendChild(domain);

            host = document.dpForm.dpAddress[i].value;

            address = "https://"+host+":9090/sys.login";
            f.setAttribute("target", "_blank");         
            f.setAttribute('action',address);
            f.submit();
        } 
     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this to work is to give the windows a unique target attribute and open them prior to submitting the form.

```
function formSubmit1() {
    len = document.dpForm.dpAddress.length
    i = 0

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (document.dpForm.dpAddress[i].selected) {

            // ... other code goes here

            address = "https://" + host + ":9090/sys.login";
            f.setAttribute("target", "window-" + i); // a unique id instead of "_blank"
            f.setAttribute('action', address);
            window.open(address, "window-" + i); // pop open a window with that same id and the form will submit into it
            f.submit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a [functional demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UUd5h/1/) showing the technique in action (make sure your pop-up blocker is disabled).

Comment: I tried this in Chrome with 2 IP addresses. For one it is opening a new tab in same window and for second, it's opening a new window. I want both should be opened in new tab.