# Chrome extension context menu only works once

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm writing my first Chrome extension, it uses context menus (right-click and options come up). When text is highlighted and the `ExtensionName` option is selected from the right-click menu, it opens up a new tab and passes that as a query to a directory that my organization has. The issue is that it only works once. The option in the context menu still appears when text is highlighted and right-clicked, but selecting the `ExtensionName` option fails to produce another tab with the directory results.

I would like to for the user to be able to use this as many times as needed in a browser session, just like most other Chrome extensions. Reloading the extension in Chrome extension menu fixes the issue. I assume it has something to do with the event handling that occurs in my background script `rightclick.js`. I'm not as familiar with event handling in JavaScript or in the context of Chrome, so any help would be appreciated.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "ExtensionName",
    "description": "Right-click text to search the given directory.",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon-bitty.png",
        "48": "icon-small.png",
        "128": "icon-large.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["rightclick.js"]
    }
}
```

rightclick.js

```
var selection_callbacks = []; 

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request) { 
    var callback = selection_callbacks.shift(); 
    callback(request); 
});


function getSelection(callback) { 
    selection_callbacks.push(callback); 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file:"selection.js" }); 
};

function createDirectoryRequest(selectText) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "THE URL FOR THE DIRECTORY GOES HERE");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("id", "search_generic_search_terms);");        
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "search[generic_search_terms]");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", selectText);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form);        
    form.submit();

}

chrome.contextMenus.create({title: 'ExtensionName "%s"', 
                    contexts:["selection"], 
                    onclick: function(info, tab){ createDirectoryRequest(info.selectionText); }})
```

selection.js

```
chrome.extension.sendResponse(window.getSelection().toString());
```

I know this probably isn't a difficult problem, I'm just incredibly new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to submit a form several times with different values. Based on [Submitting HTML form multiple times with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16159818/2698119), all you have to do is to give the target of your forms a unique value and open a new tab prior to submitting the form:

**rightclick.js**

```js
var i = 0;

function createDirectoryRequest(selectText) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "THE URL FOR THE DIRECTORY GOES HERE");

    // unique target for each form; open it in a new tab
    form.setAttribute("target", "window" + i);
    window.open("THE URL FOR THE DIRECTORY GOES HERE", "window" + i);
    i++;

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("id", "search_generic_search_terms);");        
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "search[generic_search_terms]");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", selectText);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form);        
    form.submit();
}
```

Note that you could create only one form, and simply change its attributes before submitting, rather than creating a brand new form every time:

```js
var i = 0;

var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "THE URL FOR THE DIRECTORY GOES HERE");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("id", "search_generic_search_terms);");        
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "search[generic_search_terms]");
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form);   

function createDirectoryRequest(selectText) {
    form.setAttribute("target", "window" + i);
    window.open("THE URL FOR THE DIRECTORY GOES HERE", "window" + i);
    i++;

    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", selectText);    
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: I use your second option. The only hiccup I had dealt with `window.open("THE URL FOR THE DIRECTORY GOES HERE", "window" + i);`, I  had to leave the URL part blank for it to work correctly. I don't know whether that's would be a universal issue or something that is only happening because of my directory, but either way, thanks for your help!