# Chrome Extension not running everytime page action button is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension that I need to have the ability to run the content script multiple times when clicking on the page action button. I have this in my background.js:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    alert('calling content_script');
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'content_script.js'
    },function(){alert("success");});
});
```

This works the first time the button is clicked. When clicked a second time, I get my popup saying "calling content_script" but the content script is never executed. Why is this?

Here is the background script in its entirety:

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, ChangeInfo, tab){
    if(tab.url.indexOf("tiger.armstrong")> -1){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        if(tab.url.indexOf("tiger.armstrong") == 0){
            chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
        }
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    alert('calling content_script');
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'content_script.js'
    },function(){alert("success");});
});
```

Here is the manifest:

```
{
  "name": "LiveLab Post Grades",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab","tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js","background3.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "GIcon.png"
  },
    "default_title": "LiveLab Tools"
  },
   "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Here is the content script:

```
var livelabtools = {
    /**
     * this function is like window.open, but it can POST (rather than GET) from js
     * source: http://canop.org/blog/?p=426
     */
    canop_open: function (verb, url, data, target) {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = url;
        form.method = verb;
        form.target = target || "_self";

        if (data) {
            //for (var key in data) {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.name = 'data';
                input.value = data;//typeof data[key] === "object" ? JSON.stringify(data[key]) : data[key];
                form.appendChild(input);
                //console.log(form);
            //}
        }
        // these two lines are only needed for ie
        //form.style.display = 'none';
        //document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        console.log("form submit ===  " + form);
        form.remove();
    },
    post_grades: function () {
        alert('in post grades!!!!');
        var str, exercise,
        i = 0;
        grades = {};
        do {
            ex_str = "form1:tabSet1:tabInstr:lp2:tabSet4:tabp:lpProgress:ts1:tab7:lp7:table3:rg3:" + i + ":tc3:st3";
            lname_str = "form1:tabSet1:tabInstr:lp2:tabSet4:tabp:lpProgress:ts1:tab7:lp7:table3:rg3:" + i + ":tc1:st1";
            grade_str = "form1:tabSet1:tabInstr:lp2:tabSet4:tabp:lpProgress:ts1:tab7:lp7:table3:rg3:" + i + ":tc7:st7_field";
            exercise = document.getElementById(ex_str);
            lname = document.getElementById(lname_str);
            grade = document.getElementById(grade_str);
            if (exercise != null) {
                if (grades[lname.innerHTML] === undefined)
                    grades[lname.innerHTML] = {};
                    console.log(lname.innerHTML + ", " + exercise.innerHTML + ", " + grade.innerHTML);
                if (grade.value != null && grade.value != '')
                    grades[lname.innerHTML][exercise.innerHTML] = grade.value;
                else
                    grades[lname.innerHTML][exercise.innerHTML] = "0";
            }
            i++;
        } while (exercise != null);
       // console.log(JSON.stringify(grades));
       // console.log(JSON.stringify(grades).length)
        //window.open("http://aspen2.cscofc.info/jsontocsv.php?data="+JSON.stringify(grades));
        console.log('posting...' + "\n JSON.String... = "+ JSON.stringify(grades));
        livelabtools.canop_open("post", "http://aspen2.cscofc.info/jsontocsv.php", JSON.stringify(grades));        
        console.log('done');
        return "function end";
    }
}

console.log(livelabtools.post_grades());
```

I won't go into detail about it, unless asked but the important parts to note are the return statement and the console log. Everything runs perfectly fine the first time the page action button is clicked, and when finished, I get "function end" printed to the console. After the initial run, however, whenever I click on the page action button, I get an alert saying "calling content_script" and nothing else happens. Why won't my content script run more than once?

Comment: With your code, I was able to successfully execute the content script every time I clicked on the page action. Could you add your manifest and the rest of your background script (in particular how do you show the action page)?

Comment: It works perfectly.. what makes you say it doesn't? Maybe your content script is the culprit; mine is simply `console.log("I am here");`, and it logs the message as many times as I click the page action.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your problem, but do you realize that you are injecting `jquery.min.js` in every single page you visit ? Are you also aware of the fact that (according to **[this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#event-onClicked)**) your pageAction onClicked listener does not get any `tabId` parameter ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem thank you, I was trying that earlier and came across that in the api reference but never took it back out of my code. My next question would then be what is the proper way to use jQuery in my extension? Also, I have updated the question by adding the content script.

Comment: @lampwins: I'll try to take a deeper look at your code later. Some quick suggestions for now: Remove the "activeTab" permission since it is a "subset" of the already present "tabs" permission. 2. Remove the "content_scripts" key from your manifest and inject jquery programmatically from `background.js` (more on that later). 3. Try to do some debugging by adding `alert`s at various points to see at which point the actual behaviour deviates from the expected.

Comment: The issue is that you're trying to post a form several times with the same target. You can see that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19389018/2698119 for more details on how to fix this, but basically you need a different target for each form submission.

Comment: @Metoule okay, I understand that, but why does this stop `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'content_script.js'},function(){alert("success");});` from executing the content script at all the second time?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Why do I never see the alert, `post_grades: function () {
        alert('in post grades!!!!'); ... }` when the page action button is clicked a second time? Any ideas?

Comment: @lampwins: After all, it seems like when a script is already injected, it is not injected again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like when a script has already been injected it is not injected again.
So, the way to go would be to initiate your action by passing a message to the content script. (Of course, if the content script has not been injected yet, you need to inject it first.)

One solution I came up with (and after testing confirmed it works fine) is the following:

1. On `pageAction.onClicked` send a message from the background page to the content script, asking it to do something (e.g. post the grades). Also, request a response to be sent back to the background page.
   [See, also, **[chrome.tabs.sendMessage(...)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)**.]
2. If the content script has already been injected, have it receive the message, send a confirmation back to the background page and proceed doing something (e.g. posting the grades). This process can take place as many times as you want.
   [See, also, **[chrome.runtime.onMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)**.]
3. The first time that the `pageAction.onClicked` is fired, there will be no content script listening for messages. In that case, there will be no message confirmation. Instead **[chrome.runtime.lastError](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError)** will be set. In that case, the background page will have to inject the content script first and then send the message again.
   [See, also, **[chrome.runtime.lastError](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError)**.]

---

Theoreticaly speaking, that should do it !
Practicaly, this is the sample code that worked for me:

**manifest.json**:
(Note: If you have more specific requirements regarding the pages you need to access, you could incorporate them into the manifest and get rid of some of the permissions.)

```
{
    ...
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "page_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
    ...
}
```

**background.js:**

```
function checkForValidURL(tabId, info, tab) {
    var idx = tab.url.indexOf("tiger.armstrong");
    if (idx > 0) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    } else {
        chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
    }
}
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidURL);

function onPageActionClicked(tab) {
    // Send message to content script, asking to post grades
    alert("Calling content_script...");
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "postGrades" }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            // The error indicates that the content script
            // has not been injected yet. Inject it and...
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                file: "content.js"
            }, function() {
                if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    // ...if injected successfully, send the message anew
                    onPageActionClicked(tab);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The content script called our response callback,
            // confirming that it is there and got our message
            alert("Message got through !");
        }
    });
};
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(onPageActionClicked);
```

**content.js:**

```
var livelabtools = {
    /**
     * This function is like window.open, but it can POST (rather than GET) from
     * JS source: http://canop.org/blog/?p=426
     */
    canop_open: function (method, url, data, target) {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = url;
        form.method = method;
        form.target = target || "_self";

        // 'data' is an object with key-value pairs
        // of fields to be sent
        if (data) {
            for (var key in data) {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.name = key;
                input.value = (typeof(data[key]) === "object")
                        ? JSON.stringify(data[key]) : data[key];
                form.appendChild(input);
            }
        }

        form.submit();
        form.remove();
    },
    post_grades: function () {
        console.log("Posting some grades...");
        livelabtools.canop_open("POST",
                "http://aspen2.cscofc.info/jsontocsv.php", 
                "{}");
        console.log("Grades sent !");
    }
}

// Listen for messages from the background page
// (It actually listens for messages from anyone in the context,
//  but the background page is the one that interrests us)
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, response) {
    // If we've been asked to post grades...
    if (msg.action && (msg.action == "postGrades")) {
        // ...confirm we got the message and...
        response();
        // ...do what we do best: post grades !
        livelabtools.post_grades();
    }
});
```

---

Let's hope this covers it :)

Comment: What you said about single injection of the content script makes perfect sense, but is this stated anywhere in Google's documentation? (maybe I'm just bad at reading). Anyway, your solution works just fine, thanks! I would suggest one thing for future readers however, my content script is named `content_script.js` and when you make the call to inject it, you reference `content.js`. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: I couln't find any documentation about the one-time injection. My conclusion is based on observations only (that's why I wrote "*It **seems** like...*"). If you take a closer look, you'll notice I named my content script "content.js" (that's the title above the respective code-block), that's why I reference it as "content.js" in the manifest as well (but this is probably too much detail for anyone to care). I am glad it worked for you :)